# Remove Fixed Class When Image Reaches A Certain Point on the webpage

Tags: jquery, image, scroll, position, fixed

I have a webpage that requires an image to scroll down as the page move. In order to do this in my css I have assigned its class the position value of fixed. However on the page I have a footer. When I scroll to the bottom of the page the image overlaps and appears on top of this footer. I have tried using jQuery to create a function that calculates the current position of the image on the page and if the position is past a certain point make it stop at that point and not to proceed further down the page. However I am not skilled in jQuery and so I have yet to make it work.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scrollock.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <span class="navlinks">
                <a></a>
                <a></a>
                <a></a>
                <a></a>
                <a></a>
                <a></a>
            </span> 
        </nav>

        //this is the image that needs to move down the page as the user scrolls but stop at a certain point//

        <img class="map" src="Drawing.png" height="200px"></img>

        <section>
        </section>

        <section>
        </section>

        <section>
        </section>  

        //This is where the image needs to stop before//
        <section id="contact">
        </section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.map{
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: fixed;

}


#contact{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(line.png);
    margin-top: 0px;
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
var image = $('.map');
var top = $('.map').position.top();
    if( top > 300 ){
    image.css('position','absolute');
}else{
 image.css('position','fixed');
};
});
```

I really have very little idea as to what is wrong with the jquery whether its a semicolon mising somewhere or what.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: As mentioned below, your `if else` statement insn't correct. But I think think you will get there with that since your `image` has a fixed position and will never reach the if statement.

Comment: Also, watch out that this function should be called periodically (setInterval), otherwise it will only be called at document.ready.

On the other hand, as putvande has noted, you have to use offset instead of position.top

Comment: @NewToThis mind creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a link to a page to show what you want to accomplish. I have created [one](http://jsfiddle.net/8sXp5/) using the code here, but I don't see what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

your "if" statement should be wrapped into a parenthesis :

```
if(conditional_here){

  //if true

}else{

  //if not true

};
```

and also, use Firebug to inspect any of this issues or trace back any bad code / bugs your script may have